# How to use regular expression in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I am learning Scala and spark and want to get the numbers out of string.
And for that i am using the regular expression. And came to know about the weird signature of using regular patterns in Scala.

Here is my code:

```
val myString: String = "there would be some number here 34."
val pattern = """.* ([\d]+).*""".r  
val pattern(numberString) = myString
val num = numberString.toInt
println(answer)
```

The code is working fine, but seems a bit weird and less readable.

Is there any other way to do this in Scala? Or any other syntax which i can use?

Comment: Well, I am going through a similar tutorial and I am unable to grasp my mind around this syntax. It feels pretty weird to see the result part be part of a function call? `val pattern(numberString) = myString`. Could anyone explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern-matching way you are extracting the number is rather resource consuming: since the pattern must match the whole string, you have to add `.*` on both ends of the regex, and that triggers a lot of backtracking. You also added a space to make sure the first `.*` does not eat all the digits on the left and return all 1+ digits found.

If you are looking for a first match, use [`findFirstIn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#replaceFirstIn(target:CharSequence,replacement:String):String):

```
val myString: String = "there would be some number here 34."
val numberString = """\d+""".r.findFirstIn(myString)
val num = numberString.get.toInt
println(num) // => 34
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/WPOLCW39722).